# Change form select optiosn based on first select option?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a form with two select dropdown but I would like the second select box to change based on which categories equal the option name from the first select dropdown.

```
<form id="search" action="/lawyer_search" method="get" class="clearfix">
    <select name="perscorp" id="perscorp">
        <option value="">Personal or Corporate</option>
        <option value="1">Personal Law</option>
        <option value="2">Corporate Law</option>
    </select>
    <select name="lawservice" id="lawservice">
        <option value="">Select a service</option>
        <?php $query="SELECT * FROM teamcat" ; $result=$ conn->query($query); while($row = $result->fetch_object()){ $checked = $row->teamCatName == $lawservice ? 'selected' : ''; echo "
        <option value=\ "" . $row->teamCatID . "\"$checked>" . $row->teamCatName . "</option>\n"; } $result->free(); ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" id="search" class="search" name="search" value="Search" class="enquiry_btn" alt="Search" />
</form>
```

Comment: Where is your jQuery code that shows your attempt to accomplish what you want?

Comment: I have not implemented any jQuery to accomplish this, this is one thing I do not know to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Everything explain here : [link](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-add-option-select-jquery/)